# Using an array to find the multiples of two ints

Tags: java, arrays

Im a programming student and im having alot of trouble with this question:

"complete a static method multiplesOf which takes two int parameters, number and count. The method body must return an int array containing the first count multiples of number. For example,

multiplesOf(5, 4) should return the array { 5, 10, 15, 20 }
multiplesOf(11, 3) should return the array { 11, 22, 33 }
multiplesOf(1, 15) should return the array { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }

You must not use System.out.print or System.out.println in your method."

This is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    multiplesOf(5,4);
}

public static int[] multiplesOf (int number, int count) {
    int[] a = new int[count];
    a[0]= number;
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        a[i] = (a[i]*count);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Ive been trying to figure out why the array "a" still only has the values 0,1,2,3

Comment: What does `a[i] = (a[i]*count);` do?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public static int[] multiplesOf(int number, int count) {
  int[] a = new int[count];
  for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    a[i - 1] = number * i;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        public static int[] multiplesOf (int number, int count)
        {
            int[] a = new int[count];
            a[0] = number;
            for(int i = 1; i<count; i++)
            {
              a[i] = number * (i + 1);
            }
            return a;
          }
```

**output**

[5, 10, 15, 20]

Answer (score 1):

```
a[0] = number;
for(int i = 1; i<count; i++)
{
      a[i] = (i+1)*number;
}
```

Comment: ah yeah you were faster :D but I think when I see all the wrong answers I can let the answer stay here :) I will upvote you

Comment: Pretty shocking really

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int[] multiplesOf(int number, int count) {
    int[] a = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        a[i] = (number * (i+1));
    }
    return a;
}
```

use this

Comment: As OP says "You must not use System.out.print or System.out.println in your method."

Comment: *must not use System.out.print or System.out.println in your method.*

Comment: SOP isn't required; the array is supposed to just be returned, not printed.

Comment: i was just checking by printing..now changes are made.

Comment: Post you output then

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int[] multiplesOf (int number, int count) {
     int[] a = new int[count];
     for(int i = 1; i<=count; i++) {
         //a[i-1] beacuse we started iterating array at i=1
         a[i-1] = (i*number); 
     }
     return a;
}
```

multiplesOf(5, 4) returns -> the array { 5, 10, 15, 20 }